# Change image brightness in React Native without rendering component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, image-processing

I'm making a photobooth project and I need to process the image brightness before printing the image (with expo-print) without rendering a component.
I found somes libraries but they need to render the component.

I need something like Jimp to filter my image, do you know a library I could use ?

Thanks !

Comment: Nobody have an idea ?

Comment: Do you know how to change the brightness right now?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski No I didn't find a solution, so I applied a black backgroundColor on an ImageBackground and I take a capture of it with captureRef. It's not realy convenient but I did't find a javascript library to edit pictures.